# How to Protect website code PHP / JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, reactjs

I work on a website that I wrote in PHP, HTML and JS. I want to ask what's the best way to protect the code because the site can be easily copied and I want to protect it as well as possible so it won't work on another domain or to compile the source code. For example if I have to use NodeJs or a framework like react to rebuild my site or use an extension to better protect the code I'll do it. Please let me know your thoughts and if it's good to protect the site code.

Because I've worked now for over 6 months on the site and I'm very afraid of someone just copying my site with a program and uploading it to their server.

**Edit**

> The site is written in PHP just because to make maintaining the
>   site easier. I use PHP components for the Header, Footer, and Nav but the site is mostly based on HTML based elements.
>   If it's possible to maybe have the js code run only on the domain of the site and if someone tries to open the site in a different domain to block the js file that would be nice.

Looking forward to some ideas.

Comment: Your server side PHP code is not accessible to the user, unless you make it accessible. Your browser HTML, CSS and JavaScript code is no more accessible then every other website. Unless you are willing to convert to Web Assemblies you can not really protect your code. Even if you encode it, it will have to be decoded to execute. Once that happens everyone can get at it. Probably not worth the effort to try to protect JS code.

Comment: anyone can copy the rendered html/javascript of whatever site they open even google or facebook, but as long as they don't have the server-side php code it would be mostly a useless piece of code because the output never changes. anything that goes to client-side can be altered & copied and trying to protect it isn't worth the effort

Answer (score 4):

PHP is handled server-side. You don't need to worry about that :P

HTML is client side and can't be obfuscated because the client won't be able to read it.

As for JS, I would recommend something like [this.](https://javascriptobfuscator.herokuapp.com/)

**EDIT:** As for seeing if the code is running on an okay domain, use `window.location.href` in your javascript to check if the URL contains your home URL name. If it doesn't, cease loading the page.

Comment: oh ok thanks is there a way to protect my js code to just work on this site and if yes how ? so a beginner won't be able to copy the site because without the js the site is broken, I also compiled all js files to one min.js to make reading the source code a little bit harder.

Comment: Even if you do this the JS code will have to be de-obfuscated to run. At that point anyone can grab it and use it. It is probably not worth the effort to obfuscated JS code since it slows down your website and can be broken into anyway. You might want to look at Web Assemblies, but even that code can be taken by anyone and re-used.

Comment: This is exactly the same thing I told you above, the issue of obfuscating the JS code does not make it safe since all it does is minify it so that the code has a smaller size.

Obfuscate is practically the same as minifying, this in the case of JavaScript

Comment: @Cody If this solved your issue, please mark my answer as best :)

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code would be run on your server and only the intended output would be accessible by web users. There's no way to guarantee that your code cannot be accessed by a determined attacker, by exploiting vulnerabilities in your server software.

Keeping your server software up to date will help prevent unwanted access to it.

Source: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-view-a-PHP-source-code-of-a-website-just-like-we-see-the-HTML-and-other-codes

Answer (score 1):

You can do several things that I used to do before.

> 1 - You can try to obfuscate the JavaScript production code (Minification) and obfuscate the PHP code with a payment tool.
>
> 2 - You can make the components / modules render all in the PHP server.

**Note**: PHP is interpreted on the server so you really should not worry much about it, HTML, JS and CSS will always be public, however much you want to hide it, anyone will have access to it.

Comment: BTW the site is written in PHP just because to make maintaining the site easier. I use PHP components for the Header, Footer, and Nav but the site is mostly based on HTML based elements is there a way to protect the source code?

Comment: The short answer is NO, i'm sorry but not possible

Comment: Obfuscated JS code can still be downloaded, de-obfuscated and use by anyone. There is currently NO safe way to protect your client-side JS code.

Comment: That's what I mean, although this obfuscated can really continue to use unless you do conventions d enombre and all that but in the end you can use it in the same way.